# Error 13 Type mismatch in filtered Excel worksheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, filter

I have a filtered worksheet in which I need the values which are in `column N`.
This worksheet also has labels in row 1. Everything works perfect, except when I have only one row left after the filter. On that moment I get `Error 13`.
I see that the value the program is working with is the value from `cel A1`, this is a `textvalue` from the label and not the value in `column N`. Can anybody tell me what I do wrong ?

```
Dim Rng As Range
        Set Rng = Range("N2", Range("N2").End(xlDown)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        For Each cell In Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            score(y) = cell
            totaal_k = totaal_k + score(y)
            y = y + 1
        Next cell
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the error  ?

Comment: I use the columns A:N and have about 1000 rows which are filled. When I use a filter and row 641 is the only row, then I get the error. When I add one more row that is equal to the filters, then I don' t have the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this happen on every single-after-filter row or just row 641?

I think xlDown is the problem here. Is there anyway for you to predefine the last row range, or does it have to be dynamic? If there is, then I think it might be the solution. If not I'd try defining the data range differently, for example by implementing a quick function to determine last row of data. Sample can be found under this link: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1721-excel-find-last-row-column-with-data.html

Also, as a part of troubleshooting, I advise putting a breakpoint on line 4 of your excerpt above and see what values are being applied to cell and Rng.

Now that I mentioned it - it just occurred to me that you use xlCellTypeVisible twice - both on your Rng and later referring to that Rng. If you applied it when setting the variable, why use it later? Try removing that part from one of the places and see how that works.

Comment: I removed the first xlCellTypeVisible and it worked perfect. Thanks !

Comment: Glad I could help - would appreciate marking it as answered as I'm working on my rep here :-)

Comment: how do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if Rng has actually been set before interacting with its methods/properties.

```
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range("N2", Range("N2").End(xlDown))
    If Not (Rng is nothing) then
    For Each cell In Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 
    score(y) = cell 
    totaal_k = totaal_k + score(y) 
    y = y + 1 
    Next cell
    End if
```

Comment: I have used your code and the the problem is also solved. Thanks !